# nginx proxy manager 502 bad gateway at login

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, nginx-reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I followed this guide https://www.the-digital-life.com/nextcloud-nginx-proxy-manager-in-10-minutes/ to provide an TLS encryption to my nextcloud docker instance. Bevor I made anything I created a new VM, so there is nothing interfering. On it I followed the guide and configured the dockerfile like below. It looks to me, that the containers should be in the same network(). But when I try to log into npm, I am getting a "502 bad gateway". I have currently no port forwarding or static public ipv4 adr, but since this is (only needed later for letsencrypt?) and I am just accessing an privat ipv4, I figurded this should still work. Google says that this 502 bad gateway issue is most likly caused when the containers are not in the same network, since docker is seperating those. I am struggeling to find a point to go look for next, because I think they are in the same network. Maybe you guys got some ideas? Thank you in advance!

### docker-compose ps
Name                         Command               State                              Ports

nextcloud_nextcloud-app_1   /entrypoint.sh apache2-for ...   Up      80/tcp
nextcloud_nextcloud-db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh --tra ...   Up      3306/tcp
nextcloud_npm-app_1         /init                            Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:81->81/tcp
nextcloud_npm-db_1          /scripts/run.sh                  Up      3306/tcp

netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      945/containerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      860/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1019/sshd: /usr/sbi
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1016/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9741/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::81                   :::*                    LISTEN      9729/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1019/sshd: /usr/sbi
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      9715/docker-proxy

'''

trauti@trauti-stable:/opt/nextcloud# sudo cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

volumes:
nextcloud-data:
nextcloud-db:
npm-data:
npm-ssl:
npm-db:

networks:
frontend:
# add this if the network is already existing!
# external: true
backend:

services:

nextcloud-app:
image: nextcloud
restart: always
volumes:
- nextcloud-data:/var/www/html
environment:
- MYSQL_PASSWORD=kbaA-1D!5s5E
- MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
- MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
- MYSQL_HOST=nextcloud-db
networks:
- frontend
- backend

nextcloud-db:
image: mariadb
restart: always
command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
volumes:
- nextcloud-db:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ls2,a!2nJsaj1gb
- MYSQL_PASSWORD=otu-aa2!d1conq-72JhA
- MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
- MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
networks:
- backend

npm-app:
image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
restart: always
ports:
- "80:80"
- "81:81"
- "443:443"
environment:
- DB_MYSQL_HOST=npm-db
- DB_MYSQL_PORT=3306
- DB_MYSQL_USER=npm
- DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD=UsnH-1bIdb!k-Aoub!2
- DB_MYSQL_NAME=npm
volumes:
- npm-data:/data
- npm-ssl:/etc/letsencrypt
networks:
- frontend
- backend

npm-db:
image: jc21/mariadb-aria:latest
restart: always
environment:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Zqqb2-2quvAn12-1aHaSA
- MYSQL_DATABASE=npm
- MYSQL_USER=npm
- MYSQL_PASSWORD=Oia-1SfA-273Jan@
volumes:
- npm-db:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
- backend
trauti@trauti-stable:/opt/nextcloud#

'''